# Slow Integrate of a product of Boolean functions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, performance-tuning

I have

```
Integrate[
  Boole[Abs[xa] < 1] Boole[Abs[xa - xb] < 1] Boole[
    Abs[-L + xb] < 1] Boole[Abs[xa - xc] < 1] Boole[
    Abs[-L + xc] < 1], {xa, L - 2, 1}, {xb, L - 1, 2}, {xc, L - 1, 2},
   Assumptions -> {2 < L < 3}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

and get

> {0.554812, -(1/3) (-3 + L)^3}

I am in fact doing this many thousands of times, by generating these Boolean expressions from the adjacency matrices of some random graphs. Thus, it needs to be as fast as possible.

Is there a reason it takes 1/2 a second to complete?

If I run without the assumptions, it is much faster.

```
L = 2.5; AbsoluteTiming[
 Integrate[
  Boole[Abs[xa] < 1] Boole[Abs[xa - xb] < 1] Boole[
    Abs[-L + xb] < 1] Boole[Abs[xa - xc] < 1] Boole[
    Abs[-L + xc] < 1], {xa, L - 2, 1}, {xb, L - 1, 2}, {xc, L - 1, 
   2}]]
```

> {0.031514, 0.0416667}

Perhaps there is a way to convert the Boole's into a set of intervals, over which one then repeatedly integrates unity.

Comment: This is also kind of like doing: `Piecewise[{{1, Abs[xa] < 1 &&
    Abs[xa - xb] < 1 &&
    Abs[-L + xb] < 1 &&
    Abs[-L + xb] < 1 &&
    Abs[xa - xc] < 1 &&
    Abs[-L + xc] < 1}}]` though integrating this is no faster.

Comment: I don't find 0.554812 a long time.for the complicated integrand.

Comment: One of the problems is scaling up, to a longer product of Boolean functions. So if this takes 0.5secs, a longer one can take 2 hours. But better code can make it scale much better.

Comment: Sorry, this is an empty talk without a code.

Comment: I just need an efficient evaluation of the integral, it shouldn’t take 0.5seconds if done effectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 reg = ImplicitRegion[{Abs[xa] < 1, Abs[xa - xb] < 1, Abs[-L + xb] < 1,
     Abs[xa - xc] < 1, Abs[-L + xc] < 1, L - 2 <= xa <= 1, 
    L - 1 <= xb <= 2, L - 1 <= xc <= 2}, {xa, xb, xc}];
Assuming[2 < L < 3, Integrate[1, Element[{xa, xb, xc}, reg]]] // 
  Simplify // AbsoluteTiming

(*{0.142462, -(1/3) (-3 + L)^3}*)
```

Comment: Did you execute this twice to get the cached result quicker? Because it still takes 0.5 seconds on my machine from a fresh kernel (must quit kernel to reset)

Comment: Your code returns `{0.249371,-(1/3) (-3 + L)^3` in 12.1 on Linux.

Comment: Yes it also takes 0.5 secs for me.

Answer (score 3):

```
J = ImplicitRegion[
  Abs[xa] < 1 && Abs[xa - xb] < 1 && Abs[-L + xb] < 1 &&
  Abs[xa - xc] < 1 && Abs[-L + xc] < 1 &&
  L - 2 <= xa <= 1 && L - 1 <= xb <= 2 && L - 1 <= xc <= 2, {xa, xb, xc}];

Assuming[2 < L < 3, RegionMeasure[J]]
(*    1/3 (27 - 27 L + 9 L^2 - L^3)    *)
```

is very quick.

Comment: Nice, the timing is 0.05secs.

Comment: It takes 0.516816 sec in version 12.0 on Windows 10, whereas the code from the question takes 0.938683 sec and the code by @cvgmt takes 0.464822 sec.

Comment: Of course, `ClearAll["Global`*"];` was executed every time in the above.

Comment: For general L, it is a bit faster. But for specific L=5/2 it is very quick.

Comment: But the @cvmpt's code is faster: 0.110171 vs 0.0809927.

Comment: You are correct, @cvgmt is marginally faster, both with and without a specific value for L.

Answer (score 1):

If you you only need a numerical result for given  `L` try

```
int[L_?NumericQ] :=NIntegrate[
Boole[Abs[xa] < 1] Boole[Abs[xa - xb] < 1] Boole[
Abs[-L + xb] < 1] Boole[Abs[xa - xc] < 1] Boole[
Abs[-L + xc] < 1], {xa, L - 2, 1}, {xb, L - 1, 2}, {xc, L - 1,2} ]


int[2.5] // AbsoluteTiming 
(*{0.0222419, 0.0416667}*)
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm also finding it much faster for specific L. But is there a way to speed it up for generic L?

Comment: Your first `Integrate` gives you the analytical result depending on  generic `L` which might be evaluated thousand times. My solution `int[L]` holds for generic `L` too!

Comment: Yes, but I can't see the function. I'm essentially looking for what the function is. The values perhaps are a bit less important.

Comment: But this is in fact useful in itself.